# Run a PHPUnit Selenium 2 test case programatically (“within PHP”)

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

this is relevant question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047777/run-a-phpunit-selenium-test-case-programatically-within-php/5048029#5048029)
and i did like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048029/1337119)

```
require_once 'SeleniumTestCase/Driver.php';
$driver = new PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase_Driver();
$driver->setBrowser('*firefox');
$driver->setHost('localhost');
$driver->setPort(4444);
$driver->setTimeout(30000);
$driver->setBrowserUrl('http://www.google.com');
$driver->start();
$driver->open('/');
```

and it works fine but there is no cssselector or way to get attribute values like size (width - height) so i think using  Selenium2 is better so i check

https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/

and i found the same issue with selecting element (note: there is select by id and class but there is no nested selector like this selector `("div.father  div#child")` in this example i can get father but i cant get the child for this specific father) so what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Once you want to do anything beyond the basic 'open a page and click a link' commands in Selenium, [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) becomes the best way of navigating around a document. For example, if you wanted to test the width of `div.father div#child`, something like (untested):

```php
$driver->assertEquals("//div[@class='father']/div[@id='child']/@width", "500");
```

There are plenty of resources about on the subject. [This tutorial](http://hedleyproctor.com/2011/05/tutorial-writing-xpath-selectors-for-selenium-tests/) has a detailed run though, if you ignore where it breaks into Java at the end.